# A question on Robinson's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have a question on the proof of the statement 3.2.8 in Robinson's book ( A course in theory of groups) [Robinson's book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-0128-8) . 
On the first part of the proof, A is $n \times n$ diagonal block matrix and every block $a_i I_{n_i},i=1,...,k$ is of degree 1 x 1. Here I don't know what do $ I_{n_i}$ means?. I am a little bit confused on subscript of the identity.

[proof of statement 3.2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1gs2.png)

Answer (score 2):

$I_{n_i}$ is simply the $n_i \times n_i$ identity matrix.

Comment: But here $a_i I_{n_i}$ is 1 by 1 why the identity is of degree $n_i$.